# Unable to deploy with "Invalid index" error when using AWS Adapter with CDKTF

Tags: terraform-cdk

When I use AWS Adapter in CDKTF and create PublicSubnet, the following error occurs and I cannot deploy.
I can deploy with no problem using PrivateSubnet.
Perhaps there is a problem with the route to the Internet gateway in the route table, as the error message says.

Please let me know the solution.

```
   │ Error: Invalid index
   │ 
   │   on cdk.tf.json line 53, in resource.aws_route.adapter_VpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRoute3DA9E72A_5BE14C48 (adapter/VpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRoute3DA9E72A):
   │   53:         "gateway_id": "${jsondecode(aws_cloudcontrolapi_resource.adapter_VpcIGWD7BA715C_6AEEE500 (adapter/VpcIGWD7BA715C).properties)[\"Ref\"]}",
   │     ├────────────────
   │     │ aws_cloudcontrolapi_resource.adapter_VpcIGWD7BA715C_6AEEE500 (adapter/VpcIGWD7BA715C).properties is "{\"InternetGatewayId\":\"igw-05191b9e55b006ed3\",\"Tags\":[]}"
   │ 
   │ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

The actual code is as follows

```js
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { App, TerraformStack, S3Backend } from "cdktf";
import { AwsProvider } from "@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/provider";
import { AwsTerraformAdapter } from "@cdktf/aws-cdk";
import { Vpc, IpAddresses, SubnetType} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    new AwsProvider(this, "AWS", {
      region: "us-east-1",
    });

    const awsAdapter = new AwsTerraformAdapter(this, "adapter");

    const vpc = new Vpc(awsAdapter, 'Vpc', {
      vpcName: 'cdktf-test-vpc',
      ipAddresses: IpAddresses.cidr('10.1.0.0/16'),
      maxAzs: 1,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          cidrMask: 24,
          name: 'Public',
          subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}

const app = new App();
const stack = new MyStack(app, "cdktf");

new S3Backend(stack, {
  bucket: "tfstate-bucket",
  key: "cdktf.tfstate",
  region: "us-east-1",
});

app.synth();
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code you have?

Comment: @MarkoE
Yes
This is a modified version of the main.ts generated by running the "cdktf init" command

Comment: Ok, and where is the gateway referenced in the code you have in your question?

Comment: @MarkoE
Since subnetType is specified as Public in the VPC constructor, the gateway is automatically created.